# Setting up dynamic allocation in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am following the instruction [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#configuration-and-setup) for setting up dynamic allocation for YARN resource manager.

However, I am confused by step 3: `Add this jar to the classpath of all NodeManagers in your cluster.`

Does this mean go to each node server and add the path to `shuffle.jar` to `PATH` environment variable? `export=$PATH:<loc-to-shuffle.jar>`?

Comment: I once used dynamic allocation and never did that. Are you using HDP ?

Comment: What do you mean by `HDP`? I am using HDFS if that's what you are asking

Comment: Sorry, I meant Hortonworks DataPlatform.

Comment: Hm, no. Have not heard about it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yarn classpath means that on all node managers, either set the yarn.application.classpath in yarn-site.xml which contains comma-separated list of CLASSPATH entries.

When this value is empty, the following default CLASSPATH for YARN applications would be used.

- For Linux:

```
$HADOOP_CONF_DIR, $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*, $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*, $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*, $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*, $HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/*, $HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*
```

- For Windows:

```
%HADOOP_CONF_DIR%, %HADOOP_COMMON_HOME%/share/hadoop/common/*, %HADOOP_COMMON_HOME%/share/hadoop/common/lib/*, %HADOOP_HDFS_HOME%/share/hadoop/hdfs/*, %HADOOP_HDFS_HOME%/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*, %HADOOP_YARN_HOME%/share/hadoop/yarn/*, %HADOOP_YARN_HOME%/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*
```

So put `spark-<version>-yarn-shuffle.jar` in one of the listed classpath directories defined in yarn.application.classpath or the default classpath directories.

You can also create the soft link of `spark-<version>-yarn-shuffle.jar` in one of the yarn classpath directories

Hope this helps...

Comment: Do we have to do this in all node managers?

I have a cluster setup with a master and 2 workers
Spark is only installed on the master. so I can add this jar to classpath in master's yarn-site.xml. But what do i do for the worker nodes? Since i don't have spark  installed in worker nodes, i wont also have the jar .